# How to hide a button when I click the button in react using functional components

Tags: reactjs

By default I am trying to show button, Now I am trying to hide button when I click the buton in react using functional components.

This is my code

This is App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Parent from './Parent/Parent';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Parent></Parent>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is Parent.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Parent.css';


const Parent = () => {
    const [show, hide] = useState(true)

    const hideButton = () => {
        hide(false)
    }
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div className='one'>
                        <button show ={show} onClick={hideButton} className='btn btn-primary'>Click here</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Parent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `ternary` condition to show and hide value:

```
{show && <button onClick={hideButton} className='btn btn-primary'>Click here</button>}
```

Full code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Parent = () => {
  const [show, hide] = useState(true);

  const hideButton = () => {
    hide(false);
  };
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-12">
          <div className="one">
            {show && (
              <button onClick={hideButton} className="btn btn-primary">
                Click here
              </button>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Parent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-newton-1wvl1?file=/src/App.js:0-678